# Puppeteer Scrolling And Clicking Selectiors with Same Class names

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm quiet new to Puppeteer and NodeJs, so im trying to scrape a certain website where there are multiple posts that has this List element on clicking on it the comment section loads now my Qyestion Is:
I want to click all the list elements(since they all have same class name), I can click on one of them by running the following code, now I want to scroll the page step by step and click on all of them respectively.
Any help will be appreciated, and if anyone can guide me to a certain page or a video link that can help me that will be really helpfull.
Cudos!!

```
await page.click('li.social-details-social-counts__comments.social-details-social-counts__item.social-details-social-counts__item--with-social-proof');`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use page.$$ which is the same as querySelectorAll. And then in the loop click on each of these elements.

```js
const links = await page.$$(
  "li.social-details-social-counts__comments.social-details-social-counts__item.social-details-social-counts__item--with-social-proof"
);

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  await page.click(links[i]);
}
```